# Bins and Balls problem several balls at once

Tags: probability

I'm trying to calculate the expected value of the number of balls that i need to choose for fill all bins with at least one ball.

There are $N$ empty bins labeled from 1 to $N$, and infinitely many balls. How many balls in mean do I need to choose, in random way, to fill each of the $N$ bins with least one ball in the next experiment?

Choose $n$ randomly between 1 and 2. Choose  $a$ and $b$  randomly  between 1 and $N$. If $n$ is 1 then choose the bins with labels $(a+c) \% N$ and $(a-c) \% N$ and fills those each one with one ball. If $n$ is 2  then choose the bins with labels $(a+c) \% N$, $(a-c) \% N$, $(b+d) \% N$ and $(b-d) \%N$ and fills those each one with one ball. Here $c$ and $d$ are selected randomly and such that $c$ is not equal to $d$.

I calculate the expect value of balls that I need to choose when if always $n=1$ that is

$$E_{n=1}=\sum_{i\text{ is even}}^{N}(n-1)/(n-i+1)+\sum_{i\text{ is odd}}^{N}(n)/(n-i+1)$$

and then when always $n=2$ that is $E_{n=2}=(E_{n=1}/2)$. I had verified the two expect values using a code in Python and that is correct. But I do not know how get the expect value when $n=1$ or $n=2$. I thought, because the probability of $n=1$ or $n=2$ is 0.5 then the expect value when $n=1$ or $n=2$ is $$E_{n=1,2} = 0.5(E_{n=1}+E_{n=2})$$ but this does not match with my Python program. For example, $n=16$, $E_{n=1}\approx26$ and $E_{n=2}\approx 13$, then $E_{n=1,2}\approx 19$ but in my Python code that is approximately 16. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Expected # of tosses of a die to get each # at least once = 6/6 + 6/5 + 6/4 + ... +6/1 = 14.7